# Creating own marker with iconView on Google Maps

Tags: swift

I created my own marker with iconView for showing my own position. As you can see it is the green one. But every time I move the screen it is reloading my green view and it seems lagging. I don't have the same problem with the other marker shown, which are simple png.
How can I solve that? I can solve that problem by removing the line `mapView.clear()` But the result is that every loaded marker don't go away if I zoom out. So the map gets more and more crowded.

[image]

```
    func mapView(_ mapView: GMSMapView, didChange position: GMSCameraPosition) {
    
    
    mapView.clear()
    let fullCordinate =   "\(mapView.camera.target.latitude),\(mapView.camera.target.longitude)"
    networkGoogleApiConnect.fetchPoi(geoCordinate: fullCordinate)
    
    networkGoogleApi.testVariable.forEach {
        let marker1 = GMSMarker()
        marker1.position = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: $0.position.lat, longitude: $0.position.lng)
        marker1.title = $0.title
        marker1.icon = UIImage(named: "house")
        
        var dict = [String:String]()
        dict["id"] = $0.id
        marker1.userData = dict
        marker1.map = mapView
        
        
        locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()
    }
    locationManager.delegate=self
    let neuLongitudeEigenerStandort = locationManager.location!.coordinate.longitude
    let neuLatitudeEigenerStandort = locationManager.location!.coordinate.latitude
    let fullCordinateEigenerStandort = "\(neuLatitudeEigenerStandort),\(neuLongitudeEigenerStandort)"
  
    let ownMarker = GMSMarker()
    ownMarker.iconView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 20, height: 20))
    ownMarker.iconView?.backgroundColor = .green
    ownMarker.position = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: neuLatitudeEigenerStandort, longitude: neuLongitudeEigenerStandort)
    ownMarker.title = "Eigene Position"
    ownMarker.snippet = "GPS"
    ownMarker.icon = GMSMarker.markerImage(with: .blue)
    ownMarker.map = mapView
    
}
```

Comment: Why are you creating a maker inside the didChange delegate ? You can create it in viewDidLoad or after any responce.

Comment: Every time someone moves the screen a new API request is made. And to every response I create a marker. How can I create a marker in viewDidLoad when the request is not made. Or did I understand something wrong?

Comment: Use idleAtCameraPosition delegate instead of change or do after API responce.

Comment: Thank you for your recommendation. But how does this solve the problem? I would just change the way I do a request and create the marker after that. And with every move I would do a new request and reload the view. My question is why don't I have the problem with the gym icon which is a png?

Comment: it might be icon view takes more time to create an icon from the view. Both have different things. but by using idleAtCameraPosition delegate this will be fix.

Comment: I tried it now with what you said and used     'func mapView(_ mapView: GMSMapView, idleAt idleAtCameraPosition: GMSCameraPosition) {'
 But the problem is still left.